# SQL Update same row multiple times with IN

Tags: sql

So say i am keeping track of how many things are in a container,
but i want to move multiple items from one container to another.

Moving the items from other containers is easy

```
UPDATE Item SET ContainerID = 2 WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

This moves item 1-6 to the container with ID 2, in containers i am keeping track of how many items is in a container, so i want to decrease the amount in the containers where the items came from.

Lets say the items 1-6 came from ContainerID 3-8, i would just query

```
UPDATE Containers SET Contains = Contains - '1' WHERE ID IN (3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

But if the items 1-4 came from ContainerID 1 and items 5-6 came from ContainerID 3, i cannot just go

```
UPDATE Containers SET Contains = Contains - '1' WHERE ID IN (1,1,1,1,3,3)
```

As this only decreases ID 1 and 3 by 1, is there any way to run this so it subtract from the Contains field for every occurrence of the id in my list?

Comment: I think you might want a trigger . . . or to calculate these values on the fly using a query.

Comment: Which RDBMS do you  use ?